# mysql startup, shtudown and logging on osx

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, logging, startup

I am trying to troubleshoot some mysql problems (I have a table I cant seem to delete or drop, it hangs forever)

I have 10.5.8 osx, I dont remember how/if I installed mysql, here is what I know:

it automatically starts on boot

the process looks like this:
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/var/Joels-New-Pro.local.pid
_mysql      96   0.0  0.0    75884    684   ??  Ss   Sat06PM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

when I run:
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --verbose --help

it says:
/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld  Ver 5.0.45 for apple-darwin9.1.0 on i686 (Source distribution)

it seems to use my.cnf from 
/etc/my.cnf

Now here are my questions:
I dont see anything in the startupitems that remotely looks like mysql

ls /Library/StartupItems/
BRESINKx86Monitoring    ChmodBPF        HP IO           HP Trap Monitor     Parallels       ParallelsTransporter

1.) So how does it startup automatically?

2.) How do I start & stop this type of installation?

Also, looking at the config, the logs have no values:

/usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --verbose --help|grep '^log'
log                               (No default value)
log-bin                           (No default value)
log-bin-index                     (No default value)
log-bin-trust-function-creators   FALSE
log-bin-trust-routine-creators    FALSE
log-error
log-isam                          myisam.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes     FALSE
log-short-format                  FALSE
log-slave-updates                 FALSE
log-slow-admin-statements         FALSE
log-slow-queries                  (No default value)
log-tc                            tc.log
log-tc-size                       24576
log-update                        (No default value)
log-warnings                      1

3.) Does that mean there is no logging enabled in mysetup?

thanks in advance!
Joel

Answer (score 2):

This is the stock Apple version of MySQL. It will most likely be running under `launchd`. Try this

*as root*

```
launchctl list | grep mysql
```

If it is running you can stop it with the command

```
launchctl stop com.mysql.mysql
```

and start it with

```
launchctl start com.mysql.mysql
```

*note:* the name of the process may not be `com.mysql.mysql`, but will match what you find in the first command.

Answer (score 0):

from my experiences of mysql on osx, in system preferences there is normally an icon in there associated with it which will allow you to control its startup and shutdown easier than using the command line.

sorry i cannot help with the other problems as ive not really got into the inner workings of it that much on osx.